# Using DataView with DataGridView breaks connection with BindingNavigator

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataview

Having trouble with a form with both a Datagridview control and a BindingNavigator control.
Initially I had the following code:

```
BS = New BindingSource(DS, dsTable)  ' (earlier code) Dim BS as New BindingSource
BNV1.BindingSource = BS     ' A BindingNavigator
DGV1.DataSource = BS        ' A DataGridView
```

Everything worked well but when I inserted a new row it was displayed at the end of the DataGridView's list and I wanted it to show in the correct sequential location.

I found a recommendation in a forum somewhere that suggested using a DataView on the Datatable to solve this issue.  I tried it and it worked great - almost.
Here's the new code:

```
BS = New BindingSource(DS, dsTable)
DV.Table = DS.Tables(dsTable)       ' (earlier code)  Dim DV as New DataView
DV.Sort = DS.Tables(dsTable).Columns(0).ColumnName
DGV1.DataSource = DV                 < ---- instead of the BindingSource 'BS'
BNV1.BindingSource = BS
```

New records were displayed right in the correctly sequenced location - but -
 The BindingNavigator did not change as I scrolled the DataGridView.  It never reflected the correct record number.
 But when you clicked on the BindingNavigator's moveNext, Previous, Start and End arrows it changed the count correctly.  Nothing happened in the 
 DataGridView but it seems like the BindingNavigator was tracking something else behind the scenes.  I suppose it was the original table.

Any idea how to get the BindingNavigator sync'd to the DataView?  So the DatagridView and BindingNavigator are looking at the same data?

(I know I can solve this by refilling the DataGridView each time but that seems wastefiul in resources.)

Additional Info: Code that actually does the Insert/ADD

```
Dim NewRow As DataRow = DT.NewRow
modCommonMaint.FillNewRow(NewRow, pnlData, dicFields)
NewRow(CntText + 1) = 0
NewRow(CntText + 2) = NewRow(0).ToString
LastAdd = txtID.Text.ToUpper.Trim
DT.Rows.Add(NewRow)
DGV1.Refresh()
Try
  DA.InsertCommand = cmdA
  DA.UpdateCommand = cmdU
  DA.Update(DS, dsTable)
Catch ex As Exception
  Console.WriteLine("Error" & ex.ToString)
Finally
End Try
```

This is the code that actually does the INSERT/ADD.  It does NOT change under either scenario. To change the behavior all I do is swap the lines in the first 2 code blocks of this note.

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you insert a row and it is added to the end of the grid. It isn't clear why you need to use the DataView - I can reproduce your issue, but have no problem at all with just using the binding source and the source of the grid.